# Fetch Custom app permission for all users through SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, custom-profile

I have a custom app say recruitment which is enable for a few custom profiles. I want to find out for which profiles the app is permitted true and for which profiles it's permitted false.

Is there any way through SOQL?

Comment: PermissionSet only have access to sObject eg Account or any other custom object. i want to find my solution for custom App.

Comment: I don't think Custom App Permission is exposed through SOQL however you can get it using Metadata API with field [applicationVisibilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm?search_text=applicationVisibilities) for profiles as well as permission sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SOQL Query on PermissionSet Object as below

```
SELECT Name,Label,iSCustom, PermissionsTransferAnyLead,ProfileId FROM PermissionSet Where Label='Garage Developer'
```

Go through PermissionSet object field to look on list of Permission details you can get.